# Find Distinct Elements in a List of Integer without using distinct() method using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have been asked the following question in a recent Java interview:

> Find a list of distinct elements from a list of integers without using `distinct()` method
> using Java 8 Stream API only.

It is obvious to use `distinct()` method with Stream API for that purpose. But I was specifically asked to use something else.

Comment: list.stream().collect(Collectors::toSet); What about this?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor `Collectors::toSet` - is an incorrect syntax, you have to provide a *collector*, not a *function* returning a *collector*. It would not compile.

Comment: It obviously should be `Collectors.toSet()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this interview question properly, you were expected to demonstrate knowledge on how `distinct()` works.

According to the documentation, `distinct()` - is a [*stateful intermediate*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) operation. Under the hood, it maintains a `LinkedHashSet` to insure *uniqueness* of the elements and at the same time preserve the initial *order* of the stream (if the stream is ordered).

In case if we don't care about the order, we can store elements into a general purpose implementation of the `Set` interface - `HashSet`. That's how we can write this code using a stream:

```
List<Integer> uniqueElements = new ArrayList<>(
    sourceList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())
);
```

And I guess that you might be also expected to make a conclusion that there's **no** need to generate a *stream pipeline* and then make use of a *collector* just in order to dump all list elements into a *set*. Because it's a convoluted and less efficient way to do the same thing that can be done by using a parameterized constructor of the `HashSet` class:

```
List<Integer> uniqueElements = new ArrayList<>( new HashSet<>(sourceList) );
```